# How to invoke a function in parent component from nested child component in Angular 1x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a parent component say `purchaseComponent` and a child component say `supplierComponent`. Supplier component works independently when I load it in a full view. Also I am successfully loading the `supplierComponent` in a modal inside `purchaseComponent`.

What I need is when I click `addSupplier` button which is in `supplierComponent` it should complete its current functionality and then call `hide` method from `purchaseComponent`.

**supplierComponent**

```
angular.module('TestApp').component('addsupplierComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'addsuppliercomponent/addsupplier.html',
    controller: AddsupplierController,
    controllerAs: 'addsupplierCtrl'
});

function AddsupplierController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.addSupplier = addSupplier;
    function addSupplier(){
        console.log("supplier component")
    }
}
```

**purchaseComponent**

```
angular.module('TestApp').component('purchaseComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'purchasecomponent/purchase.html',
    controller: PurchaseController,
    controllerAs: 'purchaseCtrl'
});
function PurchaseController(ProductService, LogService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.hideModal = hideModal;
    function hideModal(){
        console.log("Hide Modal")
    }
}
```

**purchase.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="card-content table-responsive">
            <addsupplier-component></addsupplier-component>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Result I need: once I click `addSupplier` from `purchaseComponent`, output should be

```
Supplier component
Hide Modal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> will `[child]Component` work independently without passing any parameter? coz I want this to work as an independent component too

To have the child component able to function independently, make the expression `&` binding optional with `&?` and check before invoking:

### Child Component

```
app.component('childComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'component/child.html',
    controller: ChildController,
    controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
    bindings: {
        onDone: '&?'
    }
});

function ChildController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.done = function done(){
        console.log("child function")
        vm.onDone && vm.onDone();
    }
}
```

### Parent Component

```
app.component('parentComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'component/parent.html',
    controller: ParentController,
    controllerAs: 'parentCtrl'
});
function ParentController(ProductService, LogService){
    var vm = this;
    vm.hideModal = hideModal;
    function hideModal(){
        console.log("Hide Modal")
    }
}
```

### parent.html

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="card-content table-responsive">
        <child-component on-done="parentCtrl.hideModal()">
        </child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

By using optional expression `&?` binding, the child component can operate independently:

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

From the Docs:

> All 4 kinds of bindings (`@`, `=`, `<`, and `&`) can be made optional by adding `?` to the expression. The marker must come after the mode and before the attribute name. This is useful to refine the interface directives provide.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the hide function in the component bindings

Check the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

**addsupplierComponent**

```
angular.module('TestApp').component('addsupplierComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'addsuppliercomponent/addsupplier.html',
    controller: AddsupplierController,
    controllerAs: 'addsupplierCtrl',
    bindings: {
        hideModal: '&'
    }
});

function AddsupplierController(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.addSupplier = addSupplier;
   function addSupplier(){
      vm.hideModal()
  }
}
```

**purchase.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="card-content table-responsive">
        <addsupplier-component hide-modal="purchaseCtrl.hideModal()"></addsupplier-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will supplierComponent work independently without passing any parameter? coz I want this to work as an independent component too

Comment: no, if you don't have the function you will get an exception but you can check the existence of the hideModal function in the controller or you can pass an empty function from the template